# How could I replace a substring with a variable?

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I have a string in the following format:

```
$string = 'I am {{[1,100]}}'
```

How could I add to this and replace instances of `{{[x,y]}}` with a random integer between those values?

In the example provided, the string would become:

```
$string = 'I am 47'
```

Comment: Probably `preg_replace_callback` and use the matches in `rand` function.

Comment: @user3783243 Could you provide an example with my use-case please?

Comment: @Barmar I did, I've included what I have but not sure where to go from here - was able to get the first stage working but not sure what to do for the other.

Comment: BTW, if you change the keys of your array to include the `{{}}`, you could just call `strtr()` once instead of looping with `str_replace()`.

Comment: @Barmar It is also completely reproducible

Comment: The first stage works, so that's not your question. Your question is just about the second stage, and you haven't shown any attempt to solve it.

Comment: Can you use `{{var1}}` instead of `{{$var1}}`?

Comment: @Barmar Because I don't know what to do lol. I've tried things and they don't work - but the things I've tried would be irrelevant. You're assuming I have the solution but just missing a semi-colon or something

Comment: @user3783243 Nope

Comment: You'll need to do some work but can start with https://3v4l.org/tNS54

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `preg_replace_callback()`. This uses a function to compute the replacement from the matched part of the input. The function can use `rand()` to return a random number in the given range, which come from the capture groups in the regexp.

```
$string = preg_replace_callback('/\{\{\[(\d+),(\d+)\]\}\}/', function($matches) {
    return rand($matches[1], $matches[2]);
}, $string);
```

Comment: Hey bud, a little unrelated question; What is it called when you create a function inside of calling a function like you did above? I am trying to learn about that but don't know where to even look as I dont know what its called xD

Comment: It's an anonymous function. https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for your help my friend :)